# Working with $_GET

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo, get

Hello and first off happy new years from the USA to every one around the world. I have been doing a lot of reading today on $_GET and exactly what it does and how useful it will be to implement it in my system.

To get to the point :

I have a system that tracks students. Said system will then be able to allow counselors at the University to work with a student specifically, adding comments on the job the counselor has done for the student. - > Now what I mean is that a if a counselor accepts the student a session is created (not a php session but a actual session between the student and the staff member "counselor")

My specific system will need to get the meeting_id from the url. so the url will go like so : localhost/student.php?id=1 or 2 or 3 or 4 (and so on)

From my understanding using $_GET : 
I can take the specific url id (example : localhost/student.php?id=1) and use $_GET['id'] to update a specific row in a data base table.

My question is :

Is my understanding of $_GET legitimate? I will be working with sessions, I will have SSL enables on all pages of my system (or intranet if you want to call it that). I will be using PDO to update/write/select from my database tables. I want to know if this is a proper way of implementing $_GET and if it is a safe way.

[Reading these answers / comments make me hesitant to go on with this logic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682480/how-do-i-make-get-more-secure) But with this specific usage of $_GET would it be good practice to implement this logic?

Answer (score 3):

The $_GET method is just as safe as anything else. It is what you do with it when you get it that makes it unsafe. Just make sure that you validate the $_Get in some manner before you use it in your database query. Such as, if you know the id will be an integer and you know what the max length can be, check for these things before you use it.

Answer (score 2):

> use $_GET['id'] to update a specific row in a data base table.

You **never ever** want to use $_GET to make any changes to a database, only selects. $_GET can be bookmarked and inadvertently used again.

Think of it this way. If you want to be able to bookmark something, like comments made by a certain counselor then $_GET is perfect.

If you are making changes to a database you want to use $_POST. Of course you still can't trust the user, you'll want to make sure they're authenticated and you will want to scrub any incoming data. If you are using PDO make sure to bind the data in the query statement

Comment: Yes of course @ the PDO part. I will just continue to read on about $_GET. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The passed variables will be visible in the url when $_GET method is used.Since you are building a site with important data its better to use $_POST so that the varaible names & values won't be visible. Also validate all user input fields throughly.

Comment: Since the $_GET variables are visible in the URL, a user could change the URL to change what variables are pulled up.  So like Arunu said, you might want to use $_POST

Comment: Alright I guess I haven't read up on this enough. To my understand (please correct me if wrong) the variables that are passed in this situation is the .php?meeting_id=1? that is just a generic primary key I am using in the table just to make unique sessions between a counselor and a student. is this the variable that must be protected?

Comment: $_POST isn't any safer in that regard. All the data is still contained in the header info. It's just slightly harder to spoof the data.